# Ability to detect the filename of the currently downloaded file and cleanup of the downloaded file

Tags: testrigor

Ability to detect the filename of the currently downloaded file and cleanup of the downloaded file.

For downloaded file need ability to be able to grab the filename of the downloaded file as sometimes the filename can be dynamic.
Also need the ability to cleanup the downloaded file after the verifications are complete.

Comment: The question is very vague. Please provide more specifics. Refer to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If the name is visible in the UI, we can grab it, store it, and then use a string with parameters to validate using that command.

And to validate the name of the file by saying check that file "someName.pdf" is downloaded, we can validate it.

Cleaning up is necessary since every browser or VM will start fresh every time.